# How to use import instead of require in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have following js file (non ES6 file):
(Other questions on SO, are about importing a ES6 type module, but here I am looking for importing a non-ES6 type module using import syntax.

== abc.js

```
module.exports = {
  checkSomething: function(a,b) {
     console.log("Checked");
   }
}
```

Now I want this to import in my some other file, using "import" syntax.

```
import abc from './abc';
```

Is that possible to do that?

NS: My project is currently mix of ES6 and non ES6 codes. So, I am able to use import with ES6 kind of modules, so was wondering if I can do same for above case.

Comment: You need to use `babel`.

Comment: I am already using babel and able to import the modules which are writted in ES6. But some of the files (like above) are non-es6 type file. So I am trying to import that non-es6 file into my new file (which I am writing in ES6 type)

Answer (score -2):

It means you are using ES6 in your code so you can do it easily.
If an error occurs during use of Import then use babel-script npm.

Comment: is there any further configuration for using `babel-script`?